# Button click error, stating cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript

html code

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Hello world</p>
    <button id="yourButton">My button</button>
    <script src = "script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript code

```
document.getElementById("yourButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("Button clicked!");
  });
```

the console with give a cannot read properties of null error

For an alert to to happen when the button is clicked

Comment: We can't reproduce this error - please provide more information.